# Is it possible to disable the main zoom level which you can set in IOS-Settings?

Tags: ios, zooming

The problem is, if the zoom level is very high, my app looks not that good.

Comment: When you ask a question - put your problem,the research and sample code you did and the actual output you want

Answer (score 0):

The zoom level just scales up the next smaller iphone UI, so on an iPhone6 it scales up an iphone5 UI and on a 6+ it scales up an iPhone6 UI.

No, you cannot disable it

Comment: thanks for that answer. Is it possible to check if it is enabled or not?

Comment: Not directly, not that I'm aware of anyway.. But you can do it by checking hardware codes against window size in points